# How do I change secondary horizontal (value) axis font to white?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-charts

I have tried to use the `Format.TextFrame2.TextRange` but this does not work as it returns a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.TextFrame2` object that contains text formatting for the specified chart element. It is read only.

I need to set the Secondary Horizontal (value) Axis to white.

```
Excel.Axis LineAxis = (Excel.Axis)ChartMemory.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);
        LineAxis.MinimumScale = 0;
        LineAxis.MaximumScale = 1;
        LineAxis.MajorTickMark = Excel.XlTickMark.xlTickMarkNone;
LineAxis.Format.TextFrame2.TextRage // but these are read only , and I need to set them
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried so far? It's hard to offer help when there is not much detail provided.

Comment: Update with what I have done so far, appologies should have included code :(

Comment: I am not sure I am reading your question right, but did you try .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Color?

Comment: Thanks guys this is correct I just had to change the value to "white"